# How can i invoke a JavaScript function within a Blazor PWA project?

Tags: javascript, blazor, progressive-web-apps, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to use an `Progressive Web Application` html template within a server side `Blazor` project of mine.

For the last 4 days I am having great challenges with it, since all the menus and animations of the template, are implemented with `JavaScript` within a single file `custom.js` having the following structure.

[image]

Within the `_Host` file, i have placed the appropriate include

```
<body class="theme-light" data-highlight="highlight-red" data-gradient="body-default">

    <div id="preloader"><div class="spinner-border color-highlight" role="status"></div></div>

    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

    <component type="typeof(Menu_settings)" render-mode="Static" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/custom.js"></script>

</body>
```

What i noticed is that, if i create a razor component (from the template, `Menu_Settings`) and place it within the `_Host` file it works as expected, **if it is marked as static**.

Strange things happen, (actually nothing) if i place the same component within the `MainLayout.razor` page.

For this reason i tried using the `JavaScript Runtime`, to make the magic.

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<PageTitle>Hello World</PageTitle>

<div id="page">
    <Footer_bar></Footer_bar>

    <div class="page-content header-clear-medium">
        @Body    
    </div>

    <Menu_settings></Menu_settings>

</div>


@code{

    private IJSObjectReference js { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            try
            {
                    js = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./scripts/custom.js");
                    await js.InvokeVoidAsync("init_template");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Logger.LogError($"Failed to load JS module. Error: {ex}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now i have two issues.

1. The component still refuses to work (should display a popup menu).
2. I get the error `Could not find 'init_template' ('init_template' was undefined).` when `InvokeAsync` is called.

I also tried editing the `custom.js` file like so, with the same error..

[image]

Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **export** keyword did the trick.

```
export function init_template(){

}
```